# VBA codes only works on first sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to edit a workbook with 17 sheets and each one has list of cities in the column A and I want to delete rows where they don't equal values in an array I have created in the code below. This code works on a sheet by sheet basis, but once I try to loop it, it does not work.

```
    Sub myDeleteRows()

Dim MyCol As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim core_cities As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet

core_cities = Array("Bristol", "Birmingham", "Cardiff", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne", "Nottingham", "Sheffield")

lRow = 140

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

For i = lRow To 4 Step -1

    If IsError(Application.Match(Range("A" & i).Value, core_cities, False)) Then
    Rows(i).Delete
    End If

Next i
Next sh

MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a break point in the code and stepping through it manually to work out what is going on?

Comment: Is it always lRow = 140?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple fix. Your loop was not referencing `sh` which means only the active sheet was being changed. The only changes below (aside from indentation) are the additions of two `sh`s.

To make your code more efficient, you could vary `lRow` so it picks up only rows containing entries (unless all your sheets will only ever have 140 entries).

```
Sub myDeleteRows()

Dim MyCol As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim core_cities As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet

core_cities = Array("Bristol", "Birmingham", "Cardiff", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne", "Nottingham", "Sheffield")

lRow = 140

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For i = lRow To 4 Step -1
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, core_cities, False)) Then
            sh.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next sh

MsgBox ("complete")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to reference each worksheet as you loop through them.

```
Sub myDeleteRows()

    Dim MyCol As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim core_cities As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    core_cities = Array("Bristol", "Birmingham", "Cardiff", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Newcastle-upon-Tyne", "Nottingham", "Sheffield")

    lRow = 140

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        with sh
            For i = lRow To 4 Step -1

                If IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, core_cities, False)) Then
                    .Rows(i).Delete
                End If

            Next i
        end with

    Next sh

    MsgBox ("complete")

End Sub
```

Note .Range and .Rows when inside the With ... End With and not simply Range or Rows. The prefix period (e.g. `.` ) provides the associated parent worksheet reference to sh.

Answer (score 4):

You need to qualify the range with the Sheet reference otherwise the range used in the code will always refer to the active sheet only.

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For i = lRow To 4 Step -1
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, core_cities, False)) Then
            sh.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next sh
```